# Java memory mapped binary search

Tags: java, nio, mmap

I'm currently trying to find the fastest way of searching a 2GB binary file within java.  This is different to my normal problems, as this file is already memory-mapped into the Linux file system using `mmap`.

The file is question is a binary file, and I need to search it for a fixed four byte string; `AXL0`

Normally, on smaller files, I'd just buffer it, convert it to a string, and then regex it.  However, as this file is already memory-mapped, and is quite large, the idea of re-buffering it seems wrong, and also converting it into a 2GB string seems even more wrongerer...

After some reading, I've come across the Java `NIO` packages along with `FileChannels` and `MappedByteBuffers`, but I'm not entirely sure how to set them up.

I just need to scan the file, from zero to the last byte in the file and locate each instance of the four byte string.

If anyone could offer some advice or input, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: There's an example of using regular expressions with NIO and MappedByteBuffers in the Grep example at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/example/index.html (may give you a hint how to use it for binary file)

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44021/fast-way-of-searching-for-a-string-in-a-text-file

Comment: This is not how memory mapping works. You can pretty much forget about the file being mmaped by some other program. Just read it using some buffered reader and per partes look for your pattern. If you want more info, hit me, I'll try to come up with longer answer.

Comment: Fox; the file has been mapped into the Linux file system as /tmp/scanme, does that help/hinder anything?

Comment: Ok, what exactly do you mean by "mapped into filesystem"? As `mmap` does the oposite (maps the file from filesystem to memory). What app/command do you use to do that mapping?

Comment: What I mean is that a binary file is present under /tmp/scanme, this was created by mmap from another application.  It has made a portion of the other apps memory available, which is /tmp/scanme.  If that makes sense?

Comment: Kind of makes sense. `mmap`ping actually makes no difference for you. It only presents the file (or part of it) as a memory region of the application. It does not mean the whole file is present in memory and OS itself handles how much of the data is actually cached (and it is used for all applications accessing the file). Just work with the file as usual. see @Durandal's answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the task abstractly, you can't do anything better than a linear search.

From there follows it won't likely matter much which API you use to actually perform the search, for simplicity I would simply go with a buffered InputStream, which can be implemented agnostic of the actual data source and has no inherent limit preventing it from working on files larger than 2GB.

As long as you chose a reasonable buffer size (read: not too tiny) you should get reasonable performance (as in close to the actual I/O speed limit, except maybe for an SSD because your scan may take longer than the actual I/O in that case).

Edit: Following KISS you get a few lines of code that should do just fine

```
public class ScanForByteCombo {

    public static List<Long> scanFor(InputStream is, int needle) throws IOException {
        List<Long> foundOffsets = new ArrayList<>();
        InputStream bs = new BufferedInputStream(is, 0x10000);
        int data = 0;
        int b;
        long offset = 0;
        while ((b = bs.read()) != -1) {
            data = (data << 8) | b;
            if (data == needle) 
                foundOffsets.add(offset);
            ++offset;
        }
        return foundOffsets;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        int needle = ('A' << 24) | ('X' << 16) | ('F' << 8) | '0';

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("your file")) {
            List<Long> found = scanFor(is, needle);
            System.out.println(found);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("scan took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms. Acceptable?");
    }

}
```

While it looks mighty inefficient you will probably have to go to great lengths to actually improve performance by a *noteworthy* amount.

Comment: If you are doing truly binary search, be careful with the buffer boundaries. If the bytes you are looking for cross the boundary, you might miss it.

Comment: Yeah this is something I'm aware of.  I'm just having a think as to the best way of implementing it.  I'm guessing a fixed sized buffer, but this also has the problem of boundaries.

Comment: @Tony Try the KISS version before making it complicated. See edit

Comment: Thanks for the code, I'll see what I can do.